# Why is the use of asterisk necessary in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

As i want the input to show only objects,animals,sports, why does adding an asterisk to make it *categories is able to filter the categories into objects,animals,sports and ignore  any other words after that? Like how does adding an asterisk works in this case?

```
import random

# Store the category and values into a dictionary
categories = {
    "objects": ["tables", "ladders", "chairs"],
    "animals": ["chicken", "dog", "cat"],
    "sports": ["basketball", "soccer", "rugby"]

}

response = input(' One among the following [%s] : \n' % ', '.join(map(str, list((*categories,)))))
```

Comment: It's called a splat operator, not asterisk in Python

Comment: @cricket_007 alright, but how does adding "splat operator" works here? Like as such it only filters out the categories and ignores the words after that..

Comment: Maps are iterables. A normal foreach loop will only get the map keys, not the key value pairs

Comment: There's a lot that is unnecessary.  `response = input('One among the following [%s] : \n' % ', '.join(categories))` is the same result.

Comment: @cricket_007 actually i have tried to look out for the meaning of iterables on google and stackoverflow but still couldn't grasp the meaning of it. Why are maps iterables?

Comment: Or `response = input(f'One among the following [{", ".join(categories)}]: ')` on Python 3.6+.

Comment: Because it's a collection of key value pairs. You can loop over them, therefore iterable

Comment: @cricket_007 "A normal foreach loop will only get the map keys, not the key value pairs " so i suppose the map keys here are the categories like "objects" then the key value here refers to  ["tables", "ladders", "chairs"],?

Comment: So i just have to include a colon like "objects": to make it a map key otherwise it wont be a map key?

Comment: I think you understand, but I would suggest going through the official python tutorial online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a breakdown:

```
import snoop

categories = {
    "objects": ["tables", "ladders", "chairs"],
    "animals": ["chicken", "dog", "cat"],
    "sports": ["basketball", "soccer", "rugby"]

}

snoop.pp.deep(lambda: ', '.join(map(str, list((*categories,)))))
```

Output:

```
................... categories = {'objects': ['tables', 'ladders', 'chairs'], 'animals': ['chicken', 'dog', 'cat'], 'sports': ['basketball', 'soccer', 'rugby']}
........... (*categories,) = ('objects', 'animals', 'sports')
....... list((*categories,)) = ['objects', 'animals', 'sports']
... map(str, list((*categories,))) = <map object at 0x10d261520>
', '.join(map(str, list((*categories,)))) = 'objects, animals, sports'
```

Iterating over a dictionary yields its keys, hence `(*categories,) = ('objects', 'animals', 'sports')`.

Most of the code is pointless:  `', '.join(categories)` would work just as well. Each of the following is independently redundant and could be left out:

- `map(str, ...)`
- `list(...)`
- `(*...,)`

Comment: so can i say that i  have to include a colon like "objects": in my list to make it a map key otherwise it wont be a map key for using map function?

Comment: Like without adding the colon,  will the ', '.join(categories) works?

Comment: `map()` is a builtin function which iterates over its argument. `{"objects": ...}` is a dictionary, sometimes called a *mapping*, not to be confused with `map`. The two concepts are not really related: `map` will work on lots of things (in the original code it's being used on a list). The important point is that iterating over a dictionary yields its keys. So yes, `', '.join(categories)` is sufficient, think of it as `', '.join(categories.keys())`

Comment: sorry can i check with you does adding * to categories to become *categories means im trying to iterate over a dictonary or if i ask in other way; which part of the codes indicate interation?

Comment: and when i use input(lambda:' One among the following [%s] \n' % ', '.join(*category_lists,)), it gives me the output " function category.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000001AC24D19598>" instead of the one you shown. Why is this so?

Comment: and what is the meaning of lambda here in this case? Sorry for asking so many basic questions. I'm new to python so there are so many basics i have yet to know...

Comment: `(*categories,)` iterates over `categories` and spreads the result into a tuple, hence `('objects', 'animals', 'sports')`. `lambda` is required to debug with [`snoop.pp.deep`](https://github.com/alexmojaki/snoop#ppdeep-for-tracing-subexpressions) - you shouldn't use it in your actual code.